# How cotranscription events affect splicing?

Tags: transcription, splicing

I want to know how and how often does cootranscription takes place? Can transcription regulators influence splicing during cotranscription?

Comment: Can you give some background to why you are asking? Is this a study question or based on your own research?

Answer (score 1):

Co-transcriptional splicing (CTS) is very widespread. Different studies (which are done on different cell types) report different frequencies of CTS. Most of them report a frequency of ~0.8 in different cells except for mouse liver which was reported to have a frequency of 0.45
This is the [article](http://f1000.com/prime/reports/pubmed/23638305) that summarizes these different studies.

*Can transcription regulators influence splicing during cotranscription?*

Yes.. including factors such as nucleosome positions.. this [post](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/8743/transcription-factor-binding-site-located-in-intron/8751#8751) may be helpful.